# React.js "this" is undefined in render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs and created component for testing.
Here is my code.

```
class TestComponent extends React.Component {

    A(){
        //content here
    }

    B() {
        //content here
    }

    render() {
        let ts = true;
        if(ts==true){
            submenu_items.push(<NavItem glyph='icon-fontello-search' eventKey={3} onClick={::this.B} name={B}/>);
        } else {
            submenu_items.push(<NavItem glyph='icon-fontello-gauge' eventKey={4} name={application} />);
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <div className='sidebar-nav-container'>
                    <Nav style={{marginBottom: 0}} ref={(c) => this._nav = c}>
                        {submenu_items}
                        <NavItem glyph='icon-ikons-logout' href='#' onClick={::this.A} name='A' />
                    </Nav>
                </div>
           </div>
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see here I created two functions in component.

I triggered two handleClick events.

One is inside the return function `{::this.A}` and the other is in the outside of return `{::this.B}`

Unfortunately A function is triggered perfectly but B is not triggered.

It shows error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'B' of undefined"`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure about `name={B}`?

Do you have the type error on click?

Comment: yes. don't care about name. You can reset name as const i.e. name="B"

Comment: Well, you're using ES7 syntax for binding and it should be working fine but... could you try old ES5 way by: this.A.bind(this) or ES6 anonymous functions by: () => this.A() to isolate the problem?

Comment: And what if you do `::this.A` instead of ::`this.B`

Comment: if I try ::this.A instead of this.B show undefined error as well

Comment: The biggest difference I see is that B is set on the submenu items, while A is set on the component itself

Comment: Icepickle it doesn't matter since both functions are bound to this.

Comment: @YuriyYakym but what is `this` for an element in the array?

Comment: @Icepickle `this` will always be current instance of `TestComponent` since function is bound to it.

Comment: @YuriyYakym but clearly this is undefined somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe submenu_items.push is clobbering {this}. this becomes submenu_items instead of the react component.

You can alias this before that statement like:

```
if(ts==true)
{ var thisB = ::this.B; 
  submenu_items.push(<NavItem glyph='icon-fontello-search' eventKey={3} onClick={thisB} name={B}/>); }
```

Comment: I think the cause is correct, but not the solution, this would break the push (cause it would then try to push it to the component)

Comment: I believe you are right @Icepickle. In that case would aliasing this be the only option?

Comment: I think `submenu_items.push(<NavItem glyph='icon-fontello-search' eventKey={3} onClick={::this.B} name={B}/>);` does not create function context. It's just an object literal.    URL: t.co/kcNg5Uypzj

Comment: if(ts==true){
      var thisB = ::this.B;
      submenu_items.push(<NavItem glyph='icon-fontello-search' eventKey={3} onClick={thisB} name={B}/>);
    }